# Why does this string match even though parts of it are in negative lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

Why does this regex

`(?!(public|private|protected|abstract|final|static))(.*)\(\);`

match this string:

`public Test();`

even though I said that I want an empty space, then **no** `(public|...)` and then some stuff and then `();`? What am I doing wrong here?

But I want to match this: `Test();`

Edit:

Why does this not work (no matches found), even though regex101.com matches `Test();`?

```
final String test = "public class Test {\n" +
        "  Test();\n";

final Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("^  (?!(public|private|protected|abstract|final|static))(.*)\\(\\);");
final Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(test);

while(mtchr.find())
    System.out.println("FOUND");
```

Comment: Because `ublic` is valid. You need to anchor your pattern at the start of the string `^` or at a word boundary `\b`

Comment: How can I tell regex at also `ublic` and `blic` are not valid?

Comment: Just add the `^` anchor then: https://regex101.com/r/elNHHW/1

Comment: What is the language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem

The issue you're having is shown in the snippet below. The regex is matching because your regex is not anchored to a location in the string. What this means is that the regex will try to match at each location in the string.

The regex will attempt first to match at `p` in `public Test();`. Since the negative lookahead includes `public` it will fail and try the next location: `u` in `ublic Test();`. Since `public` and the other terms don't exist at this location, it matches successfully!

```js
var s = 'public Test();'
var r = /(?!(public|private|protected|abstract|final|static))(.*)\(\);/

console.log(s.match(r)[0])
```

#### The Fix

So how do we fix this? Simple: Anchor the pattern. Adding the `^` anchor forces the regex to match from the start of the string. This means it will only attempt to match from the start of the string (the location of `p` in `public Test();`) and will not attempt to match wherever the start of the string is not (it will not try to match on the `u`).

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/elNHHW/1)

```
^(?!(public|private|protected|abstract|final|static))(.*)\(\);
```

```js
var a = [
  'public Test();',
  'Test();'
]
var r = /^(?!(public|private|protected|abstract|final|static))(.*)\(\);/

a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(r.test(s) ? s.match(r)[0] : '*** no match')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question, it doesn't work with Java Regex :(

Comment: @binaryBigInt because your string is different than the sample you provided.

Comment: @binaryBigInt try `(?<!(?:public|private|protected|abstract|final|static)\s{1,1000})\b(\w+)\(\);`

Comment: What is different? I copied the string 1:1 into java